# Is it possible to restart a display driver?

Tags: windows-8.1, display-driver

Is it possibe to restart the display driver during a normal desktop session ?

In the driver section of "Computer Management" there is no option.

But possibly there is some tool or command line to do so?

Comment: I doubt it's the same in Windows Eigh--what?! You again? Lol

Comment: What? Again ? Who ?

Comment: @DavidPostill suggested that this post be marked a duplicate. But I argued that it probably isn't the same for Windows 8. Then I realized I've seen him in another post. He must be busy on this site.

Answer (score 1):

I did a lot of research to derive my answer. Hope this helps! A display driver is just a driver for your graphics card. You can find out exactly where it is (if you don't know already) by going [Search > Device Manager > Display Adapters > (Your Graphics Card) > Properties > Driver > Driver Details]. Now download [Device Console](http://plugable.com/2014/01/21/installing-devcon-on-windows-8-1), or [DevCon](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/311272) for short. Run it in Administrator mode, then use the restart command to reset your driver! You will need to find the driver's hardware ID in order to do so.

Comment: First of all, thanks! - Tried it already, but I am not able to restart, always says "restart failed". Looked up the usage, and started cmd.exe with admin rights, but doesn't help so far. Will keep this thread updated !

Comment: I think I found the reason: Your link is linking to a tool from 2002, which is outdated by now. However, meanwhile I tried `devmanview`, and this basically works; I just need to setup out a command line version. As for `devcon`, there seems to be a more updated version, which is included in the windows 8.1 driver development kit. I will give it try.

Comment: Right. I meant for you to read both links; one for Windows 8.1 and one for further information (commands and the like). I should've made that clear--but I'm glad you figured it out yourself!